# Flag based on ID columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to assign flags based on two ID columns and one flag.

Input :

| ID_1 | ID_2 | Flag1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 1111 | N |
| 2000 | 1111 | Y |
| 3000 | 1111 | Y |
| 4000 | 2222 | N |
| 5000 | 2222 | N |

Output:

| ID_1 | ID_2 | Flag1 | Flag2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 1111 | N | Y |
| 2000 | 1111 | Y | Y |
| 3000 | 1111 | Y | Y |
| 4000 | 2222 | N | N |
| 5000 | 2222 | N | N |

`Flag2` is calculated using `Flag1` where if any of `Flag1 = Y` partitioned by `ID_2` is 'Y' then set `Flag2 = Y` .

If all `Flag1 = 'N'` partitioned by `ID_2`, then set `Flag2 = N`

Comment: You already have the condition spell out clearly, why don't you give it a try

Comment: FYI SQL Server 2008 is well out of support now - time to upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have access to SQL Server 2008, but this works on Azure:

```
CREATE TABLE #t (ID_1 int, ID_2 int, Flag1 char(1));

INSERT INTO #t (ID_1, ID_2, Flag1) VALUES (1000, 1111, 'N');
INSERT INTO #t (ID_1, ID_2, Flag1) VALUES (2000, 1111, 'Y');
INSERT INTO #t (ID_1, ID_2, Flag1) VALUES (3000, 1111, 'Y');
INSERT INTO #t (ID_1, ID_2, Flag1) VALUES (4000, 2222, 'N');
INSERT INTO #t (ID_1, ID_2, Flag1) VALUES (5000, 2222, 'N');

WITH flg (ID_2, MaxFlag)
AS
(
    SELECT ID_2, MAX(Flag1) MaxFlag
    FROM #t
    GROUP BY ID_2
)
SELECT t.*, flg.MaxFlag
FROM #t t
JOIN flg ON t.ID_2 = flg.ID_2;
```